# Jquery unwrap in each

Tags: jquery, each, unwrap

I have a problem with my unwrap, here is my HTML code :

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    <span class="highlight" id="highlight_36">bolo</span> 
    caret 
    <span class="highlight" id="highlight_37">lapso</span> 
    bla bla bla bla
</div>
```

If i execute :

```
$(".highlight").each(function() {
    // complicated operation
    ...

    $(this).contents().unwrap();
});
```

After my each, (in my browser inspector) HTML code becomes :

```
<div id="MyDiv">
    bolo
    caret
    lapso
    bla bla bla bla
</div>
```

How to obtain this HTML code ?

```
<div id="MyDiv">bolo caret lapso bla bla bla bla</div>
```

Comment: But... does it really matter? Are you in a `white-space:pre;` mode?

Comment: Yes this is important because my DOM is modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see *why* you need this, but if you **really** need to, you can use this after your operation:

```
var el = document.getElementById('MyDiv');
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(\s|\r|\n)+/g, ' ').trim();
```

That will replace every doublespaces, linebreaks and tabulations from you string and reasign it the the element.